# Default dashboard missing from Bluemix Access Trail Service under Security category

Tags: ibm-cloud, accesstrail

I have a Bluemix user and he has manager access to his space. He wants to create a custom dashboard in Access Trail Service in Bluemix console. However, he cannot see the default dashboard that comes out of the box with the creation of an Access Trail service instance. Is there any way to get the default dashboard to display?

Answer (score 0):

To recreate the default Access Trail dashboard, open the Access Trail dashboard for your space in Bluemix where you have the problem and click **Create a dashboard**. The default dashboard for that space will be recreated.